# jspdf create empty file

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I am trying to do from my dynamic HTML(where I am taking data in tables and just text from DB), by using *jspdf* return just empty file pdf.

```html
<script>
  $("#btn-print").click(() => {
    var pdf = new jsPDF();
    pdf.addHTML(document.section, function () {
      pdf.save("report.pdf");
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: could you elaborate ? do you need to generate an empty pdf on button click ?

Comment: I need to do pdf file with all data that is in html, but now I have only an empty file without anything

Comment: please check the working example of my answer below and let me know if it helps you

Comment: the example doesn't work

Comment: what it doesnt work ? can you explain more ? ... did you try clicking generatepdf button ?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use [html2pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2pdf.js/v/0.9.0) which uses combination of `html2canvas,jsPDF` and has multiple options for a rich pdf conversion of web page

using a sample table (used static data but should work same for dynamic too)

```
function genPDF() {
var element = document.getElementById('pdfContent');
var opt = {
  margin:       1,
  filename:     'myfile.pdf',
  html2canvas:  { scale: 2 },
  jsPDF:        { unit: 'in', format: 'letter', orientation: 'portrait' }
};
 
// New Promise-based usage:
html2pdf().from(element).set(opt).save();
}
```

[See working example here](https://jsfiddle.net/7nzrvkw2/19/)

- Do not forget to include cdn links
- Hit GeneratePDF Button to download as pdf and check in downloads location